# Importing Scipy Signal (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am currently trying to get the signal package from Scipy to play nice, but I am having troubles importing. Here is my code

```
import plotly.offline as pl
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 5001)
w = chirp(t, f0=12.5, f1=2.5, t1=10, method='logarithmic')

# Create a trace
trace = go.Scatter(
    x = t,
    y = w
)

data = [trace]

# Plot
pl.plot(data, filename='basic-line.html')

# or plot with: plot_url = py.plot(data, filename='basic-line')
```

and here is the error it is throwing me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\My Code\numpy_test.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scipy import signal
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\__init__.py", line 282, in <module>
    from .bsplines import *
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\bsplines.py", line 12, in <module>
    from scipy.special import comb, gamma
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 629, in <module>
    from .basic import *
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\basic.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._ufuncs import (ellipkm1, mathieu_a, mathieu_b, iv, jv, gamma, psi, zeta,
ImportError: cannot import name 'ellipkm1'
```

I could not directly install numpy or scipy from PIP so I used the whl files from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

System:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Python 3.5.1 64-bit

Perhaps a build problem?

Comment: Which exact files did you install? scipy depends on the numpy+mkl wheel, and both scipy and numpy must also match your version of CPython (3.5) and its bitness (amd64).

Comment: numpy-1.10.4+mkl-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl

and

scipy-0.17.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl